# okta sso(partner integration)

Tags: saml, okta

I have to implement Okta SSO at a client site.

Here's the client requirements
1. Partner can directly SSO to client portal.
2. Client portal is also internally linked to 8 different web properties. Users from the partner should also be able to seamlessly navigate to these 8 web properties.

So the flow is Partner - SSO to Main Client Portal - SSO internally to one or more of the 8 web properties.

I'm thinking about the best way to architect this flow. Here are my thoughts:
1. Partner portal will be the IDP. They will send an inbound SAML assertion to client portal. Client portal will JIT provision the user in OKTA using SAML assertion.
2. I'm a little lost on the flow after this ...will I have to configure each of the 8 web properties also on the Okta SP side. How will the SSO session be maintained when the user navigates to the internal web properties ?

Please correct me if my approach is wrong or I am missing something.

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is a Hub/Spoke style architecture, where the Partner is the Spoke Okta Org, and the Client Portal is the Hub Okta Org. The Client Portal needs to authenticate into the 8 apps, and also needs you to add the Partner org as an IDP.  Configure that IDP to JIT, creating users into the group of your choice, which grants them access to the applications they need.

Next, configure a new app in the Partner Spoke org with the SAML wizard, and use the information provided from the HUB IDP entry.  Set the redirect url for that app to the app embedded link of the hub, and it should work from the Partner Portal.